# PHP Accessing local filesystem -> Warning: stat(): stat failed for file:///.../test.txt

Tags: php

I want to get informations about a file in a local filesystem.

This gets an error

```
$file = 'file:///.../test.txt';
$stat = stat($file);
```

Warning: stat(): stat failed for file:///.../test.txt

But this works

```
$file = __DIR__.'/test.txt';
$stat = stat($file);
```

Is there a chance to get the local file? Here is a hint that it should work https://www.php.net/manual/de/wrappers.file.php

Comment: Why do you have to do this via the `file://` protocol, why do you not specify the local file system path instead?

Comment: Try two dots instead of three: `'file:///../test.txt'`?

Comment: To CBroe: I have an application on a webserver and from there I want to access the local file system. With file:/// you can list the filesystem in the browser.